# Filter all IP addresses from a single line log file of 10 GB using python

Tags: python, file

Recently faced a problem in analyzing log.

"Single line log file of 10GB size needs to be read and all IP address must be printed"

Issue: Cannot read line by line to avoid memory corruption. Have to go for character by character.

Solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
def getIP():
        ip = re.compile('\d+|\\.')
        out = []
        with open("./ipaddr","r") as f:
                while True:
                        c = f.read(1)
                        if not c:
                                break
                        if ip.match(c):
                                out.append(c)
                                for i in range(14):
                                        c = f.read(1)
                                        if ip.match(c):
                                                out.append(c)
                                        else:
                                                if out:
                                                        yield "".join(out)
                                                out = []

print str([ipad for ipad in getIP()])
```

Any ideas to simplify ??

Comment: What's the file format?

Comment: Can this not be tackled with some form of regular expression?

Comment: How are these IP addresses formatted?  Are they IPv4?  IPv6?  That doesn't seem like a well-thought-out requirement.  Nevermind the design - or rather the lack of one.

Comment: Why can't you use `readline`? Newlines will end the ip address in your case.

Comment: Your solution will return _any_ collection of numbers and dots, event `4546` or `99999999999999.99999`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import re
from functools import partial

def getIP(file_name):
    ip_regex = re.compile("(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}")
    current = ""
    with open(file_name) as file:
        for c in iter(partial(file.read, 1), ""):
            current += c
            current = current[-15:]
            m = ip_regex.match(current)
            if m:
                yield m.group()
                current = current[m.endpos:]
```